# Checking local filesystem fsid from osx kernel extension (kext)

Tags: macos, filesystems, kernel-extension, xnu

I've got WA for checking what is the local fsid from within kext context, simply by reading predefined local file status.

```
static inline uint64_t get_fsid(const vfs_context_t ctx, const vnode_t vp) {
    struct vnode_attr vap;
    VATTR_INIT(&vap);
    VATTR_WANTED(&vap, va_fsid);
    vnode_getattr(vp, &vap, ctx);
    return (uint64_t)vap.va_fsid;
}
```

another option is to calculate the fsid from user-space and pass this info to the driver (using `getmntinfo`)

However, I prefer getting this data from directly from the kernel space without relying on any files currently existed. is there any KPI to support this request ?

Comment: What do you mean by "WA"?

Comment: @pmdj, I wasn't sure there's proper KPI for observing mount info ... thanks for you accurate answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all mount points in the system using the function

```
int vfs_iterate(int, int (*)(struct mount *, void *), void *);
```

For each `mount` object, you can check its fsid using

```
struct vfsstatfs *  vfs_statfs(mount_t);
```

`vfsstatfs` has an `f_fsid` field.

Both functions and the struct are declared and documented in `<sys/mount.h>`. The functions are exported in the BSD KPI.

Comment: Is it possible to figure out from `vfs_iterate` whether the file system represented by mount-point, is local or ejectable (plugged in disk-on-key)  or remote network device ?

Comment: The struct returned by `struct vfsstatfs * vfs_statfs(mount_t);` contains some relevant information for this, for example `f_mntfromname` should be e.g. `/dev/disk0s2` for block device based mount points, and `f_flags` should have `MNT_LOCAL` set.